# bootbox.prompt() Confirm form submission using

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootbox

I want to prevent form submission if someone enter wrong text in textbox. I want to user enter only **done** then submit form otherwise show a error message. In my below code not working its not prevent form from submission.

```
$('#delete_btn').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        bootbox.prompt("Are you sure you want to done the record?<br/>Write 'done' below to confirm!", function(result) {
            if(result !== null)
                result = result.toLowerCase();
            if(result === 'done') {
            } else {
                alert('please enter something in textbox');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I don't see a form here. Also, what is "done_btn"? Try to include enough of the markup you're using to demonstrate the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Are you asking how to keep the prompt dialog from closing if "done" wasn't entered?

Comment: Thanks @TiesonT.  Yes of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the dialog to stay open, add a `return false` to the callback, ergo:

```
$('#delete_btn').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    bootbox.prompt("Are you sure you want to done the record?<br/>Write 'done' below to confirm!", function(result) {
        if(result !== null){
            result = result.toLowerCase();

            if(result === 'done') {
                /* submit your form */
            } else {
                alert('please enter something in textbox');

                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

You could also always return false, and then manually close the prompt only in the successful state:

```
$('#delete_btn').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    bootbox.prompt("Are you sure you want to done the record?<br/>Write 'done' below to confirm!", function(result) {
        if(result !== null){
            result = result.toLowerCase();

            if(result === 'done') {
                /* submit your form, then... */
                bootbox.hideAll();

                // or $('.bootbox').modal('hide');
            } else {
                alert('please enter something in textbox');
            }
        } else {
            bootbox.hideAll();
        }
    });


    return false;
});
```